# How to subset variables which have NA in the values?

Tags: r, na

I have an imdb dataset where I would like to replace the missing values for budget and box_office_gross, for which I think using multiple imputation would be a way to replace the missing values.

In order to separate the numeric columns from the entire dataset and perform imputation, I tried to subset the variables

```
> NBCU_Limited <- subset(NBCU_dataLaurel_Modified, select = c(NBCU_dataLaurel_Modified$imdb_votes, NBCU_dataLaurel_Modified$runtime_min, NBCU_dataLaurel_Modified$Budget, NBCU_dataLaurel_Modified$Box_Office_Gross))
Error: NA column indexes not supported
```

But I get an error because there are NA values in the variables, I cannot negate the rest of the character columns because even they have NA's and I get the same error.

How do I get only these four variables out into a new dataframe so that I can perform multiple imputation on them.

[Sample Dataset](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tdn7saa6a6mnb32/IMDB.xlsx?dl=0)

**Update:** The error is causing because I am specifying the data.frame individually in the subset, if I do not specify data.frame and just specify the name of the variable I do not get this error. I am not sure why but that is what causes the error, so maybe this is because of my improper code.

Below is the data,

```
> dput(Sample)
structure(list(imdbid = c("tt6256056", "tt0085450", "tt5050772", 
"tt5069876", "tt0083791", "tt0083929"), title = c("Una Famiglia", 
"Doctor Detroit", "Honeytrap", "Maniac 8.2.8", "The Dark Crystal", 
"Fast Times at Ridgemont High"), plot = c("N/A", "A timid college professor, conned into posing as a flamboyant pimp, finds himself enjoying his new occupation on the streets.", 
"Simeon's evening goes horribly wrong when a young woman tries to pick him up.", 
"Maniac: a person afflicted with mania. Mania: A manifestation of bipolar disorder, characterized by profuse and rapidly changing ideas, exaggerated sexuality, gaiety, or irritability, decreased sleep and violent abnormal behavior.", 
"On another planet in the distant past, a Gelfling embarks on a quest to find the missing shard of a magical crystal, and so restore order to his world.", 
"A group of Southern California high school students are enjoying their most important subjects: sex, drugs and rock n' roll."
), rating = c("N/A", "R", "N/A", "N/A", "PG", "R"), imdb_rating = c(NA, 
5.1, NA, NA, 7.2, 7.2), metacritic = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 67
), dvd_release = structure(c(NA, 1126569600, NA, NA, 939081600, 
1099353600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    production = c("N/A", "Universal", "Array Releasing", "N/A", 
    "Sony Pictures Home Entertainment", "Universal Pictures"), 
    actors = c("Patrick Bruel, Fortunato Cerlino, Matilda De Angelis, Ennio Fantastichini", 
    "Dan Aykroyd, Howard Hesseman, Donna Dixon, Lydia Lei", "Jennifer Nelson, Daemian Greaves, Polina Vasileva, Becki Lloyd", 
    "Dimitra Aggelou, Giorgos Efthimiou, Stavroula Kontopoulou, Maria-Antouanetta Tatsi", 
    "Jim Henson, Kathryn Mullen, Frank Oz, Dave Goelz", "Sean Penn, Jennifer Jason Leigh, Judge Reinhold, Robert Romanus"
    ), imdb_votes = c(NA, 4492, NA, NA, 44862, 76980), poster = c("N/A", 
    "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjhjY2Q4NWEtYTUzZC00YjE2LTk0ZjktNzUyZjIwNmQ0YTkyXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTQxNzMzNDI@._V1_SX300.jpg", 
    "N/A", "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BZjdmZTRhYzgtOGY4MS00OGM5LWJlNmItYzJiYjZiNmVmYjhkXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNDA2NjM2ODk@._V1_SX300.jpg", 
    "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMWZlZjk1MGEtYWMzOC00N2EyLWFkOTUtZDM4NGNlY2M0YjVmXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTAyODkwOQ@@._V1_SX300.jpg", 
    "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BYzBlZjE1MDctYjZmZC00ZTJmLWFkOWEtYjdmZDZkODBkZmI2XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNjQ2MjQ5NzM@._V1_SX300.jpg"
    ), director = c("Sebastiano Riso", "Michael Pressman", "Nick Archer", 
    "Giorgos Efthimiou", "Jim Henson, Frank Oz", "Amy Heckerling"
    ), release_date = structure(c(1493596800, 421027200, 1448928000, 
    1431734400, 408931200, 398044800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
    ), tzone = "UTC"), Year = c(2017, 1983, 2015, 2015, 1982, 
    1982), Year_Groups = c("2010-2020", "1980-1989", "2010-2020", 
    "2010-2020", "1980-1989", "1980-1989"), Month = c("May", 
    "May", "December", "May", "December", "August"), runtime_min = c(97, 
    89, NA, 15, 93, 90), genre = c("Drama", "Comedy", "Short, Thriller", 
    "Short, Horror", "Adventure, Family, Fantasy", "Comedy, Drama"
    ), awards = c("N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "1 win.", "Nominated for 1 BAFTA Film Award. Another 2 wins & 4 nominations.", 
    "1 win & 1 nomination."), keywords = c(NA, "pimp|college-professor|voyeurism|voyeur|blue-panties|panties|red-dress|blonde|female-frontal-nudity|female-nudity|nude-girl|nude|bare-breasts|breasts|topless-female-nudity|scantily-clad-female|cleavage|two-word-title|reference-to-joe-frazier|reference-to-yul-brynner|mother-son-relationship|f-word|place-name-in-title|city-name-in-title|dual-identity|prostitution|independent-film|title-spoken-by-character|character-name-in-title", 
    NA, NA, "mystic|magical-crystal|crystal-shard|sword-and-sorcery|puppetry|crystal|shard|quest|evil|monster|feeding-on-energy|hidden-entrance|giant-crystal|actor-voicing-multiple-characters|planetary-alignment|reunification|three-word-title|dark-fantasy|slow-motion-scene|vampire|surrealism|christ-allegory|cult-film|sorceress|relic|race-against-time|muppet|mission|magic|kingdom|creature|good-versus-evil|directed-by-star|epic|multiple-monsters|invented-language|slavery|orrery|puppet|mutation|darkness|destiny", 
    "high-school|title-directed-by-female|females-talking-about-sex|unwanted-pregnancy|fired-from-the-job|teacher-student-relationship|irreverence|sexual-awakening|innocence-lost|ensemble-film|coming-of-age|teen-movie|high-school-teacher|advice|ticket-scalping|shopping-mall|loss-of-virginity|female-nudity|brother-sister-relationship|caught-masturbating|california|surfer|teacher|break-up|rock-'n'-roll|virgin|teenager|friendship|drugs|date|surfer-dude|blond-boy|redheaded-boy|generation-x|f-rated|vomiting|sex-scene|cult-film|breasts|jeans|hawaiian-shirt|payphone|teenage-girl|teen-sex-comedy|scantily-clad-female|reference-to-led-zeppelin|dream-girl|underage-girl|jailbait|trophy-wife|voyeur|sexual-promiscuity|sexual-desire|sexual-attraction|lust|sex-on-couch|female-rear-nudity|female-frontal-nudity|panties|cheerleader-uniform|female-removes-her-clothes|cleavage|marijuana|drug-use|teen-angst|surfing|school-life|pregnancy|masturbation|football-player|first-love|employment|bikini|stoner|rock-m... <truncated>
    ), Budget = c(NA, 10375893, NA, NA, 1.5e+07, 4500000), Box_Office_Gross = c(2.48, 
    70, 70, 124, 140, 140)), .Names = c("imdbid", "title", "plot", 
"rating", "imdb_rating", "metacritic", "dvd_release", "production", 
"actors", "imdb_votes", "poster", "director", "release_date", 
"Year", "Year_Groups", "Month", "runtime_min", "genre", "awards", 
"keywords", "Budget", "Box_Office_Gross"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Can you share your example data? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315885/what-is-the-correct-way-to-share-r-data-on-stackoverflow

Comment: And I don't think you need to retype data.frame name within `subset`

Comment: @Tung I have added the sample dataset. Yes, you are right I need not specify the dataframe$ inside subset. My bad, thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: That's good. FYI, next time you can just do `dput(head(NBCU_dataLaurel_Modified))` then post the output as part of your question

Comment: @Tung I was reading your shared link and was trying to understand I am beginner and I am trying to learn. I hope this is what you suggested.

Comment: Also please post your code, not the screenshot of your code

Comment: I did `subset(NBCU_dataLaurel_Modified, select = c(imdb_votes, runtime_min, Budget, Box_Office_Gross))` and got no error

Comment: @Tung yes, you are correct. The initial code where I entered the data.frame in the subset is giving the error `Error: NA column indexes not supported`, when you just call the variable name it is not giving an error

Comment: I am not sure of why the error is causing, but thank you for spending your time. My apologies as I guess this could have been resolved if I had properly written the code.

Answer (score 0):

The error is causing because I am specifying the data.frame individually in the subset, if I do not specify data.frame and just specify the name of the variable I do not get this error. I am not sure why but that is what causes the error, so maybe this is because of my improper code. Thanks @Tung for pointing this out.